# unity game crashes if I press home button on game circle layout screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-center, amazon-gamecircle

I have made a game on unity and added amazon game circle leaderboards in it. My leaderboards work fine but if I press android home button while on leaderboard screen and then reopen after opening other applications my game crashes...

A way out I tried was to use application.quit if home button is pressed but I cannot access android home button from unity either.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you also post this question on Unity answers as that site gets a lot more Unity specific users and content.

http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html

As for your question, do you get any error messages through logcat? I had similar issues with a different library and it ended up being a handset specific issue which could not be solved due to the closed nature of the library.

Application.quit() may not be called if the application has crashed.

Comment: Beside that I want to quit application if home button is pressed and my game only crashes when I'm on leaderboard overlay and you press home button and then you try reopening it

Comment: It's quite hard to debug something without having any code or error messages. If you connect the device to your computer, open a command prompt window and type "adb shell" followed by "logcat", you'll get the full output of the device. Check if there are any error messages output when you reenter the application. My guess would be that some part of the application isn't handling the creation/destruction of Activities correctly.